# how to compile cucumber-jvm project into .jar file(s)

Tags: jmeter, bdd, executable-jar, cucumber-jvm

how to compile cucumber-jvm project in to jar file for self executable

I am using cucumber-jvm with maven, 
below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.7</source>
               <target>1.7</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    </project>
```

I wanted to compile my project to executable jar file and use the jar file in Jmeter for performance testing

Comment: not related to your problem, but the current pdfbox version is 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to feed your Cucumber tests to JMeter as it neither has relevant test elements nor plugins to understand and run them. The options are in:

1. Add multithreading on your tests level using i.e. [Future Tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)
2. Just record your test using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Run JMeter's proxy and configure your tests to use it via [WebClientOptions](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setProxyConfig(com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ProxyConfig)) like:

   ```
   ProxyConfig jmeterProxy = new ProxyConfig("localhost", 8888);
   webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(jmeterProxy);
   ```

   When you run your tests JMeter will record the relevant requests and convert them into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. This way you will get more "clean" solution which will be scaling much better as simulating HTTP Request has much less memory footprint than kicking off a headless browser. You can even bypass correlation by using a cloud-based proxy instead of JMeter built-in one (see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more information)